# How to show top-level product categories in wordpress with get_term_children()?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy

I know that i can use  get_term_children() function to get childs for some parent for some taxonomy. For example, the taxonomy can be a product category.

For example, to display children product categories for a parent product category with ID = 70 i can use:

```
$taxonomyName = "product_cat";
    $termID = "70";
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );
    var_dump($termchildren);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

I tried, the code is working. But what is the id of "THE VERY-VERY TOP / BASE / 0-level" product category in wp?  I want to show only first-level it's parents. I tried "0" and "-1" as $termID, but no luck - it shows nothing. What is the right value?

Comment: You might wanna check these [answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25035/218789).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in these answers people have some of id. In my situation i do not know the id of some child. I just want to show only first-level elements and i think that i can do this with get_term_children()...

Comment: first-level elements of what? You better provide a hierarchy of categories as an example and explain what output you are looking for.

Comment: Top-level categories for example. For example: friuts - vegetables - drinks are the top-level categories, and they have sub categories like apple/banana/pear - potato/tomato - lemonade/juice/beer. So only friuts, vegetables, drinks to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
         'orderby'      => 'name',
         'show_count'   => false, // true or false
         'pad_counts'   => false, // true or false
         'hierarchical' => false, // true or false
         'title_li'     => '',
         'hide_empty'   => true // true or false
  );
 $product_categories = get_categories( $args );
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($product_categories as $category) {
    if($category->category_parent == 0) { //this checks for 1st level that you wanted
      echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($category->term_id, 'product_cat') .'">'. $category->name .'</a>';
    }       
 }
 echo '</ul>';
 ?>
```

References:

1. [`get_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)
2. [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Comment: Exactly what i need, 100 %. Thanks. So the aproach is to check : ```if($category->category_parent == 0)``` instead of using a very-very-top-id that seems to be not existing )

Comment: About getting a 2nd level items -  i have just completed. The approach is to use the code that you provided to get a list of top level categories, and then i use foreach() and get_terms(). So i get all sub-cats of second level for each first-level category

Answer (score 0):

so close but need to check parent:

```
$taxonomyName = "product_cat";
    $termID = "70";
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );
    var_dump($termchildren);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
        if ($term->parent==$termID) {//check parent value here
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```